# WP Как работает JSON_TABLE в mySQL для WordPress?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Подскажите, как правильно задать работу функции [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) для работы в WordPress.
Пробую реализовать пример описанный в документации с записью json данных в кастомную таблицу `sports_test`

1. Создаем таблицу в БД WP

```
function create_table3()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_test';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}
                ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  xval TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  yval TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  PRIMARY KEY (id));
                  {$charset_collate}";
                dbDelta($sql);

                $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name,
                    array(
                        'id' => 0,
                        'xval' => 'default',
                        'yval' => 'default',
                    )
                );
            }


        }
        create_table3();
```

2. Пробую записать данные как написано в примере документации. Что-то не отрабатывает синтаксис.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_clearDB', 'dataStructuring' );
function dataStructuring(){
global $wpdb;
    $tb_clear = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_test';
    $json = '[{\"x\":2,\"y\":\"8\"},{\"x\":\"3\",\"y\":\"7\"},{\"x\":\"4\",\"y\":6}]';
    $wpdb->query("
    UPDATE $tb_clear JSON_TABLE( $json,
                 '$[*]' COLUMNS ( xval TEXT PATH '$.x',
                                  yval TEXT PATH '$.y',
                                  id FOR ORDINALITY
                                  )
               ) AS  jt1 WHERE id = 1;
    ");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать ? Это в `$wpdb->query` или тут как-то по другому ?

Comment: Ну ваще.. ты передаёшь в `$wpdb2->query` аргумент-строку, обрамлённую двойной кавычкой. Однако само значение-литерал содержит символы двойной кавычки - их надо экранировать. Это первое. И второе - мне очень интересно, где ты нашёл запрос типа `UPDATE .. SELECT`? MySQL о таком извращении не в курсе.. А так-то SELECT-часть вполне корректна. https://dbfiddle.uk/btZu0Bwh

Comment: Пытался объединить,  по сути, есть синтаксис WP https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb-update , но не понятно, как тогда функция должна понимать, что надо производить обновление именно в таблице `$tb_clear` .  Понятно, что пример в SQL заработал бы... как его привязать к WP ?

Comment: ```UPDATE $tb_clear JOIN JSON_TABLE(..) tbl ON .. SET .. WHERE ..```

Comment: Это не помогло.  Выдает 500 ошибку сервера. *Текст вопроса заменил.

Comment: Если ошибка 500, то смотрите в логе в чем конкретно ошибка. И что такое в данном случае `$wpdb2`?

Comment: $wpdb2 - Создание отдельного подключения к базе данных. Это из описания https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb#:~:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%2D%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%91%D0%94  Хотя, да наверное тут я не прав. И работа же ведется с одной базой, но с разными таблицами.

Comment: В Вашем случае это точно ни к чему

Comment: Исправил, но всё равно не дает произвести запись в базу. Возможно я не правильно выполняю экранирование кавычек, но не понятно, как с этим работать, когда json приходит как есть....

Comment: @BlackStar1991 для начала просто напишете SQL запрос который будет работать, а потом уже добавляйте его в WordPress, так как Ваш UPDATE запрос на данный момент не рабочий.

Comment: Так, ведь работающий пример  SQL уже @Akina показал - https://dbfiddle.uk/btZu0Bwh  Ломается он как раз на моменте установки оного в реалии WP.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140534/discussion-between-simon-and-blackstar1991).